# How do I distinguish the difference in naming and file structure between components and mobile components in React?

Tags: javascript, react.js, vue.js

### Here is my example structure:

```
.
├── App.jsx
├── index.js
└── src
    └── components
        ├── Button.jsx
        └── Header
            └── Header.jsx
```

### Question:

1. Should I name Header.jsx inside Header folder? (I personally prefer this way insteade of `Header/index.jsx` because I though it would be better to identify in vscode tab.)
2. When It has mobile component, where should I put it and how to name it, for example:

- `a. components/ButtonMobile.jsx`
- `b. components/Button/ButtonMobile.jsx,  components/Button/Button.jsx`
- `c. components/Button/mobile/Button.jsx, components/Button/Button.jsx`
- `d. components/mobile/Button.jsx`

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community where we review working code you have written and provide suggestions on how to improve that code. I am voting to close this question because it contains no code.

Answer (score 1):

### This is one of the possibilities I tried:

```
.
├── App.jsx
├── index.js
└── src
    └── components
        ├── Button.jsx
        ├── Drawer
        │   ├── Drawer.jsx
        │   ├── DrawerMobile.jsx
        │   └── components
        │       ├── DrawerTitle.jsx
        │       ├── DrawerMenu.jsx
        │       └── DrawerMenuMobile.jsx
        └── Header
            └── Header.jsx
```

- `components/Drawer/DrawerMobile.jsx` is the root of Drawer component and is mobile version.
- `components/Drawer/components/DrawerMenuMobile.jsx` is a child component of mobile version.
- `components/Drawer/components/DrawerTitle.jsx` is a child component shared both with default and mobile.

### Some explanation:

I name `components/Drawer/DrawerMobile.jsx` instead of `components/mobile/Drawer.jsx` because：

- `DrawerMobile.jsx` more easy to identify in vscode tab.
- Avoiding imports name conflict --- `{isWide? <Drawer /> : <Drawer />}`.
- Share components inside `Drawer/`.

### What's your opinion and explanation? I'm glad to hear.